# iPhone/Android app with video content - what is the best way to manage the material?

Tags: android, iphone, video

While I have some experience putting little recorded clips in an app, storing them and replaying them with a simple button press.

now I have the requirement to encapsulate some videos with the app available at installation time. What would be the best way to store longer video material in an iPhone/Android multimedia app?

The material should be available offline. So far I just have some basic question:

1. Which target conversion format and settings would be the most appropriate for iPhone/Android?
   (is there a considerable difference between phone/tablet/device resolution - or can all practically be served with one single format ?)
2. Is there some experience how many minutes of "good" (not HD) video can be stored in total within such an app?
3. Do you know of any tutorial/sample app one could use as a starting point for ideas and/or coding ideally with some kind of innovative "sexy" features, such as overlay of touchable areas?

Many thanks!